# How do I access jquery function from click function or when an event occur

Tags: jquery

I have this below jquery function, when I include click function inside it work very fine but when I add it outside the main function it doesn't work, please how do I fix the to work effectively?

**Example 1**

```js
   (function tryBarSlot() {
      function getit(){
       alert('HH');
      }
       /* Using the onclick function here works*/
        $('#play_button').click(function(event) {
       getit();
     });
      
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play_button">TRY</button>
```

**Example 2**

```js
 (function tryBarSlot() {
      function getit(){
       alert('HH');
      }
    })();
     
    $(function(){
         //getit(); /*OR*/
     $('#play_button').click(function(event) {
      getit();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play_button">TRY</button>
```

I want the example to work.

Comment: Use the first. It can even be written `$('#play_button').click(getit);` - if not, don't make an IIFE and make getIt a member so you can do `$('#play_button').click(myObject.getit);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to access it from anywhere `window.getit = getit`

```js
 (function tryBarSlot() {
      function getit(){
       alert('HH');
      }
            window.getit = getit;
    })();
     
    $(function(){
         //getit(); /*OR*/
     $('#play_button').click(function(event) {
      getit();
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play_button">TRY</button>
```

Comment: Which is polluting the global scope

Comment: Would be more elegant with a member of some object

Comment: @PhilipJems define you functions outside of document ready, what exactly you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: "getit is not defined". getit isn't defined because it is outside the scope you are currently in.

> JavaScript has function scope: Each function creates a new scope.
>   Scope determines the accessibility (visibility) of these variables.
>   Variables defined inside a function are not accessible (visible) from
>   outside the function.

In your seconds code example you create a new scope with $(function(), therefore getit isn't accessible anymore

Comment: the first example doen't fit what am trying to do, and i can copy the whole code because is long

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have like this. Call a named function from clicked handler

```js
$('#play_button').click(getit);

function getit() {
  alert('HH');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play_button">TRY</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```js
var getit;
(function tryBarSlot() {
      getit = function(){
        alert('HH');
      }
})();
     
$(function(){
     //getit(); /*OR*/
  $('#play_button').click(function(event) {
    getit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="play_button">TRY</button>
```